# Seeking statistical approach for prediction: (categorical, quantitative) -> quantitative

Tags: medicine

I am trying to find a good statistical approach for predicting a quantitative outcome from composite variables consisting of a categorical variable and a quantitative variable.

Specifically, I want to predict the score on a mental deficiency test (a number between 0 and 10) based on brain lesions suffered by the person taking the test. Each person may have a different number of lesions (1-15), and for each lesion, I know the lesion volume (quantitative), and the region of the brain in which it occurred (e.g. temporal lobe - categorical). The sample size is approximately 280.

I understand linear regression and multiple linear regression, but I am seeking any approach (regardless of complexity) that might be effective in this situation.

PS: I am new to this site and a statistics novice; comments on how to improve the phrasing of this question would be appreciated. Please give a reason if you downvote.

Comment: Regression would be my first choice too.

Comment: If I used regression, I'm trying to think of how I would set up the model. The issue is that one person might have 1 lesion, while another might have 12. Each lesion is individually categorized based on position in the brain, and quantified in terms of volume.

Comment: Do these lesions happen all at once or are they gradual? Do you have this information? That is multiple records for each patient for each lesion?

Comment: The lesions may have *occurred* at different times, but they were all *measured* at the same time, so when each occurred is unknown.

Comment: This is going to be tough. I would suggest simplifying the problem first. Two variables: one having number of lesions, the other having total lesion volume (for all the lesions combined). Try a simple linear model with this, see how it works.